# View's skeleton is rendered and afterwards styles are applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out why my rails app is rendering a view's barebones HTML layout and applies the styles afterwards, instead of rendering the view with the styles and javascript already applied.

This is the code where I load the stylesheets and javascript files in the view:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Transit by TEMPLATED</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/skel.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style-xlarge.css" />
    </noscript>
</head>
```

This is the controller where I decide to render the view:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def index
    render 'layouts/_test'
  end
end
```

And these are the manifest files:

**application.js**

```
//= require init.js
//= require html5shiv.js
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
 /*
 *= require skel.css
 *= require style.css
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

[This is how the view looks when rendered for a second or so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7KJF.png)

[And after that second it gets the styles applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJv1J.jpg)

Comment: This is called FOUC (Flash of unstyled content). Basically, The browser starts rendering before CSS has been loaded. Maybe your CSS/JS are large files, complex or take a long time to load for another reason. You should search for information about that because there are many things you can do to alleviate its symptoms. There topic is too broad to fully address here.

Comment: Apparently the content wasn't the issue but rather where I loaded the content. I put in application.html.erb and miraculously it worked. Regardless of that I'll look into FOUC because it looks like a huge deal. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the browser work to apply styles not rails. Rails only responsibiliy is to produce and deliver HTML, css and js files.

Styles will be applied only when all css files are downloaded by browser - try to use assets pipeline and deliver just one css file with all css styles combined within. Remember about gzipping and caching those files (deliver small file to client, and cache it so there was no need to download it every time page is rendered)

Comment: Apparently the issue was that I was not using the javascript files in application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

**Browsers**

To give you some context, you have to remember something *very* important about Rails, and every other web-based language / framework -- they *all* render inside a browser.

Whilst our browsers have become extremely intricate & advanced compared to just 5 years ago, the fact remains that they still rely on HTML/CSS to make objects appear on the screen.

Thus, your question isn't really about whether the CSS will be applied before the HTML -- it's whether Rails is passing the right files / code to your browser.

--

The way Rails sends the relevant data to your front-end is the same as every other app -- a *request* you send via HTTP is handled by the web server software (most people use `passenger`, some use `apache` or `nginx`) - this sends your request to Rails, which fiddles around with the database, ultimately sending back the "compiled" HTML:

[image]

Therefore, the question you should be asking is -- how am I sending the CSS/HTML to my browser? It is the most efficient way, or am I duplicating my code needlessly?